# Library throws AssertionError making my tests fail

Tags: java, junit4, assertion, rets

I've been working on creating a unit test for my java project, and my test keeps on failing even if I made no assertions.

After reading through the stacktrace, I noticed that a method in the retsIQ library I am using is throwing an assertion error. Is there anyway I can ignore this? I'd really rather not decompile and recompile the module.

I should also mention that this exact code works fine if it's not run as a test.

Here is a picture of my test:
[image: Unit Test]

Here is a picture of it it not running in a test:
[image]

Comment: are you using a java ee container in your project? jboss? tomcat glassfish?

Comment: @gurghet No I am not

Comment: Does it really work fine if you run the same code within a totally clean main method without any prior setup?

Comment: Yes, it works as expected if its not running in a test. I added a picture showing it working.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to see why it fails in JUnit but not when called via main()?

Comment: It looks like they have their tests included in their production code and for whatever the reason is their test fails making my test fail.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume two things: 1) your project is maven-based; 2) those two code fragments are exactly the same (except for the `assertTrue(true);` line, which does nothing, by the way).

Maybe your problem is caused by the fact that "run" and "test" configurations have different classpaths. You may have a wrong version of some library in the test classpath or even miss some library, which eventually leads to this exception.

I suggest you re-check all test-scoped dependencies in pom.xml. You can also print project dependency tree using [Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) (but I'm not sure whether it can print test dependencies separately):

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

Alternatively you can go to "Project Structure" > "Modules" > "Dependencies" tab in Intellij Idea and look through all entries with "Test" scope.

Answer (score 0):

From the stacktrace, it looks like there is unexpected data found when parsing the response. The best way to diagnose the problem would set a breakpoint in `SearchCompactReader.parse()` (around line 16), and run the test in the debugger.

BTW, your test isn't a unit test. A unit test tests a single class or method in isolation. Your test appears to be hitting a live server.